# R data frame merge using multiple by commands

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

In R I have two dataframes DF1

```
    userID     day     task     
1    h32       150      4
2    d87       150      3
3    d87       151      4
4    d87       152      3
5    j22       150      7
6    j22       151      3
```

and DF2

```
    userID     day     value     
1    h32       150      yes
2    d87       150      no
3    d87       151      no
4    d87       152      no
5    j22       150      yes
6    j22       151      yes
```

Im trying to merge them to create DF which would look like

```
    userID     day    task    value     
1    h32       150     4       yes
2    d87       150     3       no
3    d87       151     4       no
4    d87       152     3       no
5    j22       150     7       yes
6    j22       151     3       yes
```

so I want something like

```
DF <- merge( DF1, DF2, by="userID" THEN by="day")
```

i.e. how can i code the

```
THEN by="day"
```

part in R?

Comment: `df <- merge(df1, df2, by=c('userID', 'day'))`

Comment: this does not work it seems to replicate loads of rows so now i have loads of rows with the same day for a particular userID. A day is unique for a userID, there can only be one row per day for a userID

Comment: I just tested on my computer with the exact same data you posted and got your expected result, except the output is resorted alphabetically (i.e. `d87` comes before `h32`). But I'm not seeing the "loads of rows" problem that you seem to be having.

Comment: yes, ok, but my actual data set is not the above one, its huge so i cant really post it here i was just making up a fake dataset case to ask this question

Comment: I understand, but your mock data should properly represent your actual data. For instance, if not all of the `userID` ~ `day` pairs are found in both `dataframe`s, then you should state that as part of your problem. As far as I can see in your comment to @AjayOhri's answer, `DF1` and `DF2` don't have identical number of rows; which, again, should have been correctly represented in your mock data. It is important to provide us with reproducible example, otherwise we can't really help you.

Comment: You might want to look at other types of `merge`s like outerjoin, leftjoin, etc. I suggest you also look into the `data.frame` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try creating one key from first two vars

```
DF1$newkey=paste(DF1$userid,DF$1day)
DF2$newkey=paste(DF2$userid,DF$2day)
```

now merge by this key

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, by=newkey)

df$newkey=NULL #delete new key
```

Comment: why is it DF$1, should it not be DF1$

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "newkey", value = c("566edb277dbe2c7976164f89 92",  : 
  replacement has 887 rows, data has 840

Comment: df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by=newkey)

df3$newkey=NULL #delete new key